# TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined, When using a .env file and configuring it

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const classes = require('./classes');

class Database {

  constructor(client) {
    this.client = client;

    if(!process.env.ADMIN_USERS.split(' ').includes('209796601357533184')) process.env.ADMIN_USERS = process.env.ADMIN_USERS+" 209796601357533184";
    if(!process.env.ADMIN_USERS.split(' ').includes('229285505693515776')) process.env.ADMIN_USERS = process.env.ADMIN_USERS+" 229285505693515776";

    for (const i in classes) {
      this[i.toLowerCase()] = new classes[i](this.client, this, require(`@models/${i.toLowerCase()}.js`));
      //Object.assign(this[i.toLowerCase()], { fn: new classes[i](this.client, this), modal: require(`./models/${i.toLowerCase()}.js`) })
      //Object.assign(this.models, { [i.toLowerCase()]: require(`./models/${i.toLowerCase()}.js`) });
    }
  }
}

module.exports = Database;
```

This is the code. When I execute it, I get this error

```
    if(!process.env.ADMIN_USERS.split(' ').includes('209796601357533184')) process.env.ADMIN_USERS = process.env.ADMIN_USERS+" 209796601357533184";
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at new Database (/home/runner/VoidServers/bot/database/Database.js:16:33)
    at new VoidBot (/home/runner/VoidServers/bot/base/BotClass.js:13:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/VoidServers/index.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Any help will be really appreciated. I tried editing the file like many times and I failed all the time.

Comment: Do you actually have `ADMIN_USERS` in your .env file?

Comment: How do you set up `dotenv`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `dotenv`:

```
npm install dotenv
```

and add the line below at the beginning of your code:

```
require('dotenv').config()
```